# VSCode python 'Unverified breakpoint' during debugging?

Tags: python, breakpoints, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm debugging my python application using VSCode.

I have a main python file from where I start the debugger. I'm able to put breakpoints in this file, but if I want to put breakpoints in other files which are called by the main file, I get them as 'Unverified breakpoint' and the debugger ignores them.

How can I change my `launch.json` so that I'm able to put breakpoints on all the files in my project?

Here's my current `launch.json`:

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "port": 3000,
            "secret": "my_secret",
            "host": "localhost"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Terminal (integrated)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Terminal (external)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput",
                "Django"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask (0.11.x or later)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceFolder}/app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "nf.session.session"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Pyramid",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/development.ini"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput",
                "Pyramid"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Watson",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/console.py",
            "args": [
                "dev",
                "runserver",
                "--noreload=True"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: All debug Options",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "module": "module.name",
            "env": {
                "VAR1": "1",
                "VAR2": "2"
            },
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "args": [
                "arg1",
                "arg2"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you try this with the experimental debugger to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: This may also be the result of not setting the justMyCode config option to false. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imports for the other modules were inside strings and called using the `execute` function. That's why VSCode couldn't very the breakpoints in the other files as it didn't know that these other files are used by the main file..

Comment: So, wat was the solution?

Comment: @dmitry You need to attach the debugger to the process running the python process (jupyter kernel in my case) to which these `execute` commands are sent to

Comment: This may also be the result of not setting the justMyCode config option to false. See the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

This may be a result of the "[justMyCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode)" configuration option, as it defaults to true.

While the description from the provider is "...restricts debugging to user-written code only. Set to False to also enable debugging of standard library functions.", I think what they mean is that anything in the site-packages for the current python environment will not be debugged.

I wanted to debug the Django stack to determine where an exception originating in my code was being eaten-up and not surfaced, so I did this to my VSCode's debugger's launch configuration:

```
   {
        // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
        // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
        // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Control Center",
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
                "args": [
                    "runserver",
                    "--noreload"
                ],
                "justMyCode": false, // I want to debug through Django framework code sometimes
                "django": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

As soon as I did that, the debugger removed the "Unverified breakpoint" message and allowed me to debug files in the site-packages for the virtual environment I was working on, which contained Django.

I should note that the Breakpoint section of the debugger gave me a hint as to why the breakpoint was unverified and what tweaks to make to the launch config:

[image: Breakpoints section of VSCode Debugger with useful tip]

One additional note: that "--noreload" argument is also important. In debugging a different application using Flask, the debugger wouldn't stop at any breakpoint until I added it to the launch config.